# weblogic 10.0 +jdk 1.5

Tags: java, weblogic

Can we build a REST based web service using WEBLOGIC 10.0 and JDK 1.5? I have already CREATED with weblogic 12 C AND JDK 1.7 WORKS perfectly but this is an old application and we need add a module where we are passing an XML to TIPCO [they prefer REST here] and in-turn receiving an XML from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jax-rs is introduced with jdk 1.5 and you can find an older version of a well known rest framework who also supports jdk 1.5 such as [apache cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

However this is highly outdated and you would be missing out many features as well as options like [spring-rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Comment: Sorry if this sound rather elementary...but JERSEY offers Spring framework integration.

Comment: Sure earlier versions of spring would also do the trick, check out http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/ and https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/jersey_1_2_is_released